# What is total number of PhDs globally? How many graduate each year?

Tags: phd, reference-request

I am interested in long-term dynamics of the number of PhDs, having recently received a PhD myself. So far, I have only been able to find bits and pieces, mostly pertaining to USA (see e.g. [here](http://ftp.iza.org/dp5367.pdf), which says that there are roughly 40k PhDs awarded annually in the United States).

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [this document](http://www.eua.be/Libraries/Publications_homepage_list/EUA_CODOC_web.sflb.ashx) you can find some data for Europe and Asia. In particular, it appears that [linked document, p. 47]:

> In 2010 an estimated 125,000 doctoral degrees were awarded in the EU alone (out of a population of 500 million), compared to 70,000 in the US (with a population of 300 million) and 16,000 in Japan (with a population of 130 million).

Probably from the [EUROSTAT](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/) portal you can find other data for Europe.